# Horizontal Scroll View, Scrolling Issue Android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am new to android programming. I am implementing a simple calculator and I am facing issues with horizontal scroll View. I am using an edit text within Horizontal scroll view. It works completely fine for the first time but as soon as I clear the screen it retains it scrolling limit, meaning that even though there are few digits on the screen I am able to scroll more than it. What I want to achieve is to limit its scrolling. Below are the screen shots and XML code.

[First Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGdaK.png)

[Second Time][2]

[It is still scroll-able even though there are few digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vj3U.png)

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsvMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:scrollbars="none"
     >

        <EditText

            android:id="@+id/mainEditText"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="55sp"

            android:textStyle="bold"

             />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: try setting to edittext layout_width @ height to wrap_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing round the layout height/width attributes, make `HorizontalScrollView` `layout_width="fill_parent"` and `EditText` `layout_width="wrap_content"` and `layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsvMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mainEditText"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="55sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Edit**:

The reason why is wasn't working before because you were telling the `scrollview` to wrap the content regardless the size of the `EditText`, so it would only scroll around the `EditText`. But if you tell the `ScrollView` to `match_parent`, it'll always be the width of the screen and then the EditText can be scroll within the parent (`ScrollView`) regardless of the size.

**Note**: use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`, `fill_parent` is now deprecated. (Although still works)

Comment: Thanks alot :) Can you please explain it why it did the trick and what was wrong previously? Once again thanks alot

Comment: Happy to help you out.